# GeoServer develop community extension auto-reload

Tags: geoserver, extensions, eclipse

I want to develop an extension for my GeoServer and I started by following this guide :
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/ows-services/implementing.html

The chapter of "Running from Source" works well with my Eclipse instance project.

Is there a way for "auto-reload" (or refresh) my GeoServer instance when I change the code in my extension ?

If I change the "Hello World" message by "Hello foo", I need to

- stop GeoServer
- refresh Eclipse project
- and re-start GeoServer

I seek a faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the only way to do it I'm afraid. Your extension jar is only read at start up.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reponse. So all developers around geoserver have to do like this? It takes about 30/40 seconds (on my side) to refresh/restart GeoServer.

Comment: As far as I know that's it - try not to make too many trivial changes

Comment: Most of geoserver development is tested with unit tests. Instead of running the whole server, just run your tests.

Comment: Ok well thank you all for your replies. I will run my tests !

Comment: I definitely don't develop GeoServer like this... but you need to place your community module in GeoServer to do what I do: create a profile adding a dependency to your community module in web/app, run GeoServer from your IDE with the profile activated, and just keep on changing stuff without (depending on your JVM, you should be able to do some changes in debug mode without having to restart GeoServer).

Comment: **some changes** is the operative phrase here I think.